# when try to replace value in .csv file it give error

Tags: python, pandas, csv

when try to replace value in .CSV file it give error 
i am using pandas

> code

```
Data=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/kumar/Desktop/filename',dtype='unicode')   
Data['Date (UTC)']= Data['Date (UTC)'].str.replace("+00:00",' ', case = False)
```

> error

```
error: nothing to repeat at position 0
```

Comment: could you show us sample df.

Comment: yes, 2019-03-13T06:29:00.5311508+00:00

Comment: can you pass `regex=False`?

Comment: where regex=False

Comment: Please show the content of your .csv file, share the output of Data.head() with us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
Data['Date (UTC)']= Data['Date (UTC)'].str.replace("+00:00",' ', regex=False, case = False)
```

O/P:

```
                      Date (UTC)
0  2019-03-13T06:29:00.5311508
```

As another issue, I think the replace should be `''` instead of `' '`.